# pass array from textbox into parameter

Tags: c#, arrays

please look at my code :

```
var translateArraySourceTexts  = Textbox.Text.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
string requestBody = string.Format(body, from, "text/plain", translateArraySourceTexts[0], translateArraySourceTexts[1], ....., to);
```

What happened is, I have a textbox to input sentences. I want the sentences are separated for each sentence indicated by "."

Then, I want to use all the array to be appended to string request body. Because currently I am using "translateArraySourceTexts[0], translateArraySourceTexts[1]
,.......translateArraySourceTexts[9999].

Please share to me your thought!

Comment: My thought: "What is your question?"

Comment: Are you looking for [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0.aspx) ?

Comment: Hi, all I want to do is to concat the array and pass it as 1 single parameter. 

so my code will become : `string requestBody = string.Format(body, from, "text/plain", concatarray, to);`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

As @Blorgbeard said OP might have wanted to use `string.Join` (actually it might be `string.Concat`) - in that case the code would look like this:

```
var translateArraySourceTexts = Textbox.Text.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
var list = new List<string>(translateArraySourceTexts.Length + 4);

list.Add(body);
list.Add(from);
list.Add("text/plain");
list.AddRange(translateArraySourceTexts);
list.Add(to);

string requestBody = string.Concat(list);
//if the strings have to be separated by some other string:
string requestBody = string.Join("separator", list);
```

If you just need the text from the array concatenated you can also use `string.Concat`:

```
var translateArraySourceTexts = Textbox.Text.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
var str = string.Concat(translateArraySourceTexts);  //use it however you want
```

Of course the easier way would be to just erase the `.`s from the string (if you don't need the array of sentences later)

```
var translateArraySourceTexts = Textbox.Text.Replace(".", "");
```

---

**Old answer** - may be useful to some

You can make a `List<string>` and pass it to `string.Format` (if I understood it correctly):

```
var translateArraySourceTexts = Textbox.Text.Split(new Char[] { '.' });
var list = new List<string>(translateArraySourceTexts.Length + 3);

list.Add(from);
list.Add("text/plain");
list.AddRange(translateArraySourceTexts);
list.Add(to);

string requestBody = string.Format(body, list.ToArray());
```

---

I thought that maybe the `body` is a format string and OP wanted to easily pass the array to `string.Format`

Comment: Hi, all I want to do is to concat the array and pass it as 1 single parameter. 

so my code will become : `string requestBody = string.Format(body, from, "text/plain", concatarray, to);`

Comment: So use `string.Concat` when you don't need anything in-between or `string.Join` if you need a separator, like in the post

Comment: by the way, can you tell me what is lenght+4 used for? 
`var list = new List<string>(translateArraySourceTexts.Length + 4);`

if I set like that, then the number of input sentences will be unlimited?

Comment: I got error like this : `System.FormatException: 'Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.'
`

Comment: @RaspiSurya 1. It sets the initial capacity of the list, so it doesn't have to resize when you're adding elements. 2. Exactly what the message says, you're using `string.Format` wrong. Read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx#Starting). What would you need it for?